# SpriteKit how to completely pause an app when it enters the background

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Making a game, and i noticed that when you press the home button, wait, then come back to the game, the method

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime  
{
if (lastUpdateTime) {
    dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
}   else {
    dt = 0;
}
lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
}
```

continues to run even when the game is in the background. This isn't good because i use this method to count the seconds that has passed since the game starts to track score, and if this runs when the app is in the background, when you come back, your score is higher than when you left. All my other methods that create nodes stop, but this one doesn't. How can i get this to pause when the app enters the background.

Comment: self.view.paused = true

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is right. It is a perfect solution. When click on pause set to skView.isPaused = true.

Answer (score 0):

So your game is paused.. but `dt` looks at a difference in time between one frame and another. So in my scene I made a bool property called `catchUp`.  When it's set to true, I will set `dt` to 0.

Heres some code

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    if self.last_update_time == 0.0 || self.catchUp {
        self.delta = 0
    } else {
        self.delta = currentTime - self.last_update_time
    }

    self.last_update_time = currentTime

    if self.catchUp {  // now we start getting delta time again
        self.catchUp = false
    }
```

When I resume my game:

```
func resumeGame(sender: UIButton!){
    gameScene.catchUp = true
    self.skView.paused = false
```

i hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem days before. I think the best solution is to use `NSNotificationCenter` with `WillResignActiveNotification` and `DidBecomeActiveNotification` methods. Other methods are available too, like `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground`, here is a very detailed picture showing all the status https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Here is my example code, in the `GameViewController.swift` file, in the `viewDidLoad()` function, add those two lines:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("myObserverMethodLeave:"), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("myObserverMethodBack:"), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

then add two functions to your `GameViewController` class:

```
func myObserverMethodLeave(notification: NSNotification) {
    DataTime.backgroundStartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("App entered background!\n")
    self.hasEnteredBackgroud = true
    (self.view as! SKView).paused = true
}

func myObserverMethodBack(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.hasEnteredBackgroud {
        DataTime.backgroundEndTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        DataTime.backgroundSingleWastedTime = DataTime.backgroundEndTime - DataTime.backgroundStartTime
        DataTime.backgroundTotalTime += DataTime.backgroundSingleWastedTime
        print("App came back! and single wasted \(DataTime.backgroundSingleWastedTime)\n")
        print("App came back! and total wasted \(DataTime.backgroundTotalTime)\n")
        (self.view as! SKView).paused = false
        self.hasEnteredBackgroud = false
    }
}
```

I track the time when the app goes into background and when the app comes back, as `DataTime.backgroundStartTime` and `DataTime.backgroundEndTime`; then subtract the elapsed time to get the real score.

Hope it helps!